# with rename GNU Linux

Tags: rename

I have files in different folders.
I want to rename specific files in each folder and its children matching a specific chain of characters: "".

So after

```
shopt -s globstar
```

I tried the different options

```
rename 's/<jpg>//g' **
rename 's/\<jpg\>//g' **
```

but nothing is working

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample input and desires output

Comment: yes, please add example inputs and outputs, also the chain of characters which should be matched

Comment: What distribution are you using? There are two different `rename` utilities with completely different syntax.